# Scrambling lines from file in Python

Tags: python, string, scramble

I have a file containing large strings, and I need to scramble each and every one of them.
This is a portion of my code which does the scrambling.

```
    for line in filein:
        zzz = line.strip('\n').split()
        yyy = list(zzz)
        random.shuffle(yyy)
        zzzz = ''.join(yyy)
        fout.write(zzzz + '\n')
```

I found something like this online and so tried to use it here. 
Except that the original file and the file supposed to containing the scrambled lines... are identical.

But if I say copy one of the lines, and do this in the python interpreter directly...

```
>>>import random
>>>zzz = "..." ###(one of my large strings would go here, for sake of space didn't put it in)
>>>yyy = list(zzz)
>>>random.shuffle(yyy)
>>>zzzz = ''.join(yyy)
>>>zzzz
```

the string that gets printed out is a scrambled version of my original string. Am I forgetting to do something really simple and stupid? Or did I miss something important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`line.split` returns a list that is only 1 element in length (the line itself) since your data presumably has no whitespace interspersed with it.  Then you turn it into a list (which does nothing other than make a shallow copy) so you end up shuffling a list of length 1 -- which leads to a not-so-random result :-).

The fix is to get rid of the `split`:

```
for line in filein:
    zzz = line.rstrip('\n')
    yyy = list(zzz)
    random.shuffle(yyy)
    zzzz = ''.join(yyy)
    fout.write(zzzz + '\n')
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the quick answer. But I thought based on your previous answers to my questions split returns a list of strings... so shouldn't zzz have been a string?

Comment: @Joe No, as you stated, it will be a list of strings.

Comment: @Joe -- `str.split` does return a list of strings.  However, if you have the string `"foobarbaz"`, then splitting it will give you `["foobarbaz"]` (a list with 1 string in it) whereas the string:  `"foo bar baz"` after splitting would be `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` (a list with 3 strings in it)

Comment: ah, so where I screwed up was I didn't tell it to look at zzz[0]. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe -- That would have worked too I suppose.  I think that the code I have posted above is a little more robust though (e.g., It'll still shuffle lines where there is whitespace interspersed throughout the data)